# Deploying SSH-configuration via Puppet: Execution of '/etc/init.d/ssh start' returned 1:

Tags: debian, puppet, debian-jessie, puppet-agent

I'm deploying a ssh-default-config via Puppet to my servers. This works fine in most cases.

But now I tried to deploy it to an OpenVZ system which was freshly upgraded from Debian 7 to 8.

Now I tried to deploy my manifest:

```
Error: Could not start Service[ssh]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/ssh start' returned 1: 
Error: /Stage[main]/Ssh::Server::Service/Service[ssh]/ensure: change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[ssh]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/ssh start' returned 1: 
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ssh::Server/Anchor[ssh::server::end]: Dependency Service[ssh] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Ssh::Server/Anchor[ssh::server::end]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ssh::Client/Anchor[ssh::client::end]: Dependency Service[ssh] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Ssh::Client/Anchor[ssh::client::end]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

You need more information and Puppet is abstracting it away from you. Log in and try to start the service in a shell to see if you get anything useful from stderr. Or, look in the logs. Lastly, roll back to a known good configuration. (There is probably something wrong with the SSH config preventing it from starting.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Aaron Copley:
Running `puppet agent --test --debug` on the failing machine will give you some insight in what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem: The dist-upgrade did not switch to systemd. So `service XYZ status` or  `systemctl status XYZ` did not return correct values.

I installed systemd and the problem was solved.